# htaccess routing to SLIM Framework functions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, slim

I moved my webhotel to a new supplier and since the move my routing in my htaccess file does not seem to work anymore (getting 404 page not found), at least not when I am calling my functions using subdomain. It works when i call it with the full path though.

**Examples:**

Does not work: http://subdomain.domain.dk/v1/test

Works: http://domain.dk/subdomain/v1/test

My old webhotel was running on an Apache server and so is the new one, so its NOT nginx (which does not support htaccess).

**My htaccess looks like this (taken from SLIM example [LINK)](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/):**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

mod_rewrite is enabled on the server and the server is running php version 5.6.15.

I tested that i can reach the folder pointed to by the subdomain by calling http://subdomain.domain.dk/v1/phpinfo.php which output the phpinfo table just fine, so my DNS record for my subdomain is working fine.

As mentioned before, i have not changed anything in my .htaccess file since i moved to a new webhotel supplier.

**My questions** is, why are my calls not routed to the index.php representing my SLIM service ?

Thanks for your time...

Comment: What does `%{ENV:BASE}` contain …?

Comment: @CBroe I believe that it is the absolute path to where the .htaccess is placed and thus also the index.ph. The reason i say believe is, because i just used the htaccess from an example on building a SLIM service :-|

Comment: Stop believing, start verifying ;) And compare the value to the one in the working version.

Comment: @CBroe the working version is the one i have posted, since it was working just 2 days ago before i switched to a new web host :)  ..

Comment: @CBroe please see my update where i tested my rewrite ..

Comment: @CBroe nevermind .. they dont support REQUEST_FILENAME so their tester cannot be used..

Comment: I meant you should find out the actual value of that environment variable in both cases, and compare them. (You said the version without subdomain was working correctly, right?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95736/discussion-between-dth-and-cbroe).

Comment: @CBroe moved the discussion to to chat

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the .htaccess from Slim documentation?

Comment: @MikaTuupola i need authorization as well which i believe requires the last line in my htaccess